# kivy layout: want to set the ratio of height of components to be 5:1

Tags: python, layout, kivy

i want to make a layout such that the height of TextInput block is 5 times to that of the button. I have tried several times but failed.

The layout code follows:

```
Builder.load_string("""
<VQCIA_SUMMARY>:
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            pos:200,100
            size:400,500
            font_size: '25sp'
            multiline: True
            text: 'Summary:'

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            pos:200,0
            size:400,100
            text: "Back Home"
            font_size: '25sp'
""")
```

while i've set the height of Textinput to be 500 and that of button to be 100, the result retains to be 1:1. what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As for the height, set `size_hint_y: 0.5` and `size_hint_y: 0.1` to TextInput and Button widgets respectively.
2. Replace `size: 400, 500` and `size: 400, 100` with `size_hint_x: None` and `width: 400`

[Widget » size_hint_y](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size_hint_y)

```
size_hint_y
```

y size hint.

size_hint_y is a [NumericProperty](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.NumericProperty) and defaults to 1.

See [size_hint_x](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size_hint_x) for more information, but with widths and heights swapped.

[Widget » size_hint](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#understanding-the-size-hint-property-in-widget)

> If you don’t want to use a `size_hint` for either the width or height,
>   set the value to None.

## Snippet

```
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.5
        TextInput:
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 400

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        Button:
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 400
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.11.0

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.5
        TextInput:
            pos: 200, 100
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 400
            font_size: '25sp'
            multiline: True
            text: 'Summary:'

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        Button:
            pos: 200, 0
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 400
            text: "Back Home"
            font_size: '25sp'
'''))
```

## Output

[image: Img01]